# How Matplotlib can show properly for NaN value in Python ? (Have pic)

Tags: python, matplotlib, nan

I am very new to Matplotlib with Python.

Like below, I have got a Dataframe like this:

[image: DataFrame]

And afterwards, I plot the graph based on the df and it turned out like this:

Black Line = hsbc_valn

Red Line = boc_valn

[image]
My question is: As the latest 4.21M (2020-07-04) is from HSBC_VALN, why it doesn't able to connect with the previous data (2020-06-03)?

Answer (score 1):

The `plot()` function will connect only the "nearest" points in a continuous line, in the same way as you would manually connect the dots in a hand-drawn graph. Since the y-data for `2020-06-12` is literally "not a number", it has nothing to plot (note that the singular point there is *not* part of the data for "HSBC_VALN") and hence has no point to connect the line to.